# Change App ID of Apple Watch App

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-watch, app-id, cfbundleidentifier

I have recently transferred some of my apps from one account to another. When I did this the App IDs also transferred. However, the App IDs did not transfer for the WatchKit Apps or WatchKit Extensions.

I have tried to upload and after the upload has completed and appears in iTunes Connect Prerelease I receive an email about `CFBundleIdentifier Collision`.

I then tried to change the App ID for the Apple Watch app and see this error when uploading:

```
Attempting to change bundle identifier from com.domain.myapp.watchkitapp to com.domain.myapp.watchkitapp2 is disallowed for bundle MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyApp WatchKit Extension.appex/MyApp WatchKit App.app.
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: just FYI "IDs" never has an apostrophe (no plural has an apostrophe)

Comment: I was using the apostrophe as they are the ID's belonging to the Apps that I transferred.

Comment: hey Tom!  good thinking, but in the specific examples at hand it should have been like this, IDs.  rock on!

Comment: Okay. Are you able to help with my question? Thanks

Comment: i'm going through this same thing with them now. they told me to delete the old app id's and recreate them on the new dev program, but that didn't work. i tried changing the app id's for the watchkit app/ext and that didn't work either. so i can't use the old app id's, but am not allowed to change them either. i'll report back here with an answer if i can ever get a build through

Comment: Any news? Did you solved it eventually? Thanks

Comment: I had to contact Apple to help transfer them over. I am still trying to get the issue solved.

Comment: @TomCoomer any progress ?!

Comment: @Mc.Lover I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple manually transferred the App ID for my Apple Watch App so I was able to upload to the new account.

Comment: They responded me back with this :`They’ve advised me that this is expected behavior, and that we are unable to the bundle Id of the app.
At this time, you may resubmit the app under a new bundle identifier. Now please keep in mind that it would be be a new app and it won’t be delivered as an update, because there is no way to change the bundle ID of a shipping app and maintain the app update mechanism.`
This is ridiculous !!!!!!