# Unable to create dedicated App ID for Watch Extention

Tags: ios, watchkit, app-id, ios-app-group

I'm having trouble creating a dedication AppId to my watch extension.

So far my app and corresponding watch app worked perfectly. I had my App ID configured using a bundle id similar to the following format: `xx.yyyyy.appName`, and the watchkit app & extension were using a wildcard appId with the relevant (and suggested) bundle id of `xx.yyyyy.appName.watchkitextension` and `xx.yyyyy.appName.watchkitapp` and everything was great.

I found out I need to change the current behaviour of my apple watch app to share some data with the parent app, and in order to do it I had to enable the `App Groups` capabilities, where I found I'm not able to do so for the watchkitextension (apparently App Group capabilities required Explicit App ID rather then wildcard App ID).

Realising I don't have a dedicated App ID I went to the member centre and tried to make one unsuccessfully. Following Apple's guidelines I'm trying to create the App ID with the same prefix of `xx.yyyyy.appName` following  `.watchkitextension`.

This results in the following error message:

> An App ID with Identifier 'xx.yyyyy.appName.watchkitextension' is not available. Please enter a different string.

No matter what string I input I get the same error. I made sure I don't have other AppId with similar bundleId associated with it. I even deleted the wildcard App ID to make sure the asterisk (*) in the last digit in the Bundle ID field of it isn't confusing things. No luck -> it became even worst. I can't recreate the wildcard App ID I had before (getting the same error)

**UPDATE**:
I found out changing the first part of the string (the `xx` part) to something different allows me to create the AppID - but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem as I need it to have an identical prefix for the bundle id of the watch extension. I thought maybe this info will be helpful to whoever try to assist.

**UPDATE2**
I've read the following stackoverflow posts, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634443/watchkit-extension-bundle-id-unavailable), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212649/change-app-id-of-apple-watch-app), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found/29272260#29272260) and many others.  No luck :(

I'm feeling a bit lost here, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this helps: I only have two AppIds. One for the Container App and one for the Extension. My App was successfully submitted two the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have app with identifier '**xx.yyyyy.appName**'

***Watch App:***

Your *Watch App must be prefixed* with the identifier ( '**xx.yyyyy.appName.watchkit**') 
*WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier* - '**xx.yyyyy.appName**'

***Watchkit Extension***

*Watchkit Extension* must be prefixed with the identifier  ('**xx.yyyyy.appName.watchkit.extension**')
The *WKAppBundleIdentifier* identifier must match with the WatchKit app bundle identifier ( '**xx.yyyyy.appName.watchkit**')